# Engineering mechanics(statics)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, statics, beam

[image: I don’t get how to get the answer to part e. Should we assume reactions at A and B in all three figures are same? If so, why?]

I don’t get how to get the answer to part e. Should we assume reactions at A and B in all three figures are same? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite this being an apparent homework question, there is merit in that the answer is not the OP's objective. The question posed appears to be about the form of the problem.

I believe the first sentence is a typographical error, as it is beam AC not beam AD, but that's not in consideration here.

If you read the problem correctly, you'll see that "reactions" at A and B are support pillars. It is valid to assume that A and B in all three figures are the same. This logic is based on (e) stating that 'a' is being replaced by 'b' in one figure and is being replaced by 'c' in the other figure. If A and B were not the same, there would be reference to that in (e).

Comment: Coming to this late, but I disagree.  As written, the question cannot be answered - whoever wrote the question left out critical information necessary to answer it. There's no good reason for assuming the pillars are assumed to have equal reactions in each case (especially since A and B each have different reactions).  It's much more likely in my opinion that the examiner's intention was to say which of a, b or c is greatest and least in the case that each is arranged for the absolute maximum moment to be as small as possible.  That is, they intend part e to follow on from part d.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same. I suppose you should calculate distances b and c for same condition as you calculated a in question d) and compare results.

Comment: But it is stated that we should give the answer without making calculations

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this part. If you understand solution and continuous load distribution than you can make reasonable assumptions.

Comment: An assumption that the reactions are equal?

Comment: Assumtion that this position gives as small as possible absolute maximum bending moment (a for constant, b for linear increasing, c for linear decreasing load).